# Firebase update query is interrupted randomly

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We store our data in Cloud Firestore. We are trying to update a column for every child under root. However, update is interrupted randomly. Sometimes the code updates 50 childs, and then 100. There is no consistency. When we run the update again from where it left, the erroneous child is updated.

We have to keep an `Updated` column since we don't know which children are updated. This is the error when the app runs in Debug Mode:

```
Firebase update() id:DW7OUeam1SAOPkZiWa8pdict:{'sil': 'Sil'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\mysource\test\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\mysource\test\venv\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 826, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "D:\mysource\test\venv\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 729, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
details = "Stream removed"
debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1594884770.722000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:*****:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Stream removed","grpc_status":2}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/mysource/test/src/arbibot/firestore/ArbotDbUtility.py", line 131, in <module>
    arbotDbUtility.add_qty_to_cross_trades()
  File "D:/mysource/test/src/arbibot/firestore/ArbotDbUtility.py", line 108, in add_qty_to_cross_trades
    self.firebase.update('cross_trades', trade['id'], cross_trade_dto)
  File "D:\mysource\test\src\arbibot\firestore\Firebase.py", line 50, in update
    doc_ref.update(dict)
  File "D:\mysource\test\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\firestore_v1\document.py", line 382, in update
    write_results = batch.commit()
  File "D:\mysource\test\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\firestore_v1\batch.py", line 147, in commit
    metadata=self._client._rpc_metadata,
  File "D:\mysource\test\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\firestore_v1\gapic\firestore_client.py", line 1033, in commit
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "D:\mysource\test\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\mysource\test\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "D:\mysource\test\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "D:\mysource\test\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\mysource\test\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.Unknown: None Stream removed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can we update every child without any interruption?

Edit:

This is the code we use to update. The `sleep()` code is used for precaution. We thought mayve Firebase could block us when updating too many records. We are not sure if that's necessary.

```
def change_process_status(self):
    path_ref = self.firebase.db.collection('processes')

    docs = path_ref.stream()
    for process_doc in docs:
        process_dto = process_doc.to_dict()
        process_dto['status'] = 'COMPLETED'
        self.firebase.update('processes', process_doc.id, process_dto)
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Could you also show us how you are updating the column?

Comment: Also you could try implement exponential backoff to see if that mitigate the issue.

Comment: @RyanJoseph I've added the update code

Comment: Could you try using [batch][1] operation instead.
You will be limited to [500 operations][2] per commit, but that is already more than what you were observing before


[1] https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes
[2] https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions

Comment: @RyanJoseph We're just trying this. However, I've 2 questions: 1) Assume I have 100K records. Do I read all of them when batch updating? I mean, does my read count increase? 2) If batch updates 500 operations, how does the batch know to fetch the next 500 records in the iteration? I mean, while in the loop, batch updates 1-500 records, and now it needs to update 501-1000. How does the batch know to fetch the next batch of records?